# Can't call my Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-mvc-4

I made my own web API and now I'm trying to make it work.
This is some code from the `App_Start > WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
    );
}
```

This is my controller:

```
public class messagesController : ApiController
{
    public string GetMessages()
    {
        return MessagesService.Get();
    }
}
```

I've tried debuggon on the line `return MessagesService.Get();`, but it doesn't even came that far..

I have a feeling that I'm missing some references, because I made all these classes with empty templates.

Comment: Please show your global.asax file as well as the URL you are attempting to use.

Comment: Are you calling the WebApiConfig.Register method in your Application_Start?

Comment: @ShaunSharples I feel really stupid/dumb now because I can't see/find any `global.asax` file, and I'm using this URL `/api/messages/getmessages` it does connect right because I see the custom IIS 404.

Comment: Try and remove the get from your getmessages. Web API sometimes does some tricky things with the word Get, Post on methods. And your global.asax should be in the root folder of your Web API project.

Comment: @ShaunSharples No difference..

Comment: Can you perhaps install fiddler and give some information on the exact http responses you are getting when trying to call your API?

Comment: I get `HTTP Error 404`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should be similar to:

```
Project
Project > web.config
Project > Global.asax.cs
Project > App_Start > WebApiConfig.cs
Project > Controllers > MessagesController.cs
```

For more info on what the Global.asax.cs should look like please see: [this link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/configuring-aspnet-web-api#services)

Also, since your Controller Action is already defined as a GET type, you could go for Messages as your method name instead of GetMessages()

What may also help you is creating a new Web Project in Visual Studio and choose Web API as the project type. This could help you understand the basic structure of a Web API project.

**Edit**

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

Here is a sample of the Global.asax file for Web API.

To add a new file:

In Visual Studio 2013

```
Open Solution Explorer.
Right-click on the project.
Add New Item.
VB or C#
Web.
General.
Global Application Class.
```

Comment: It exactly the same, except that I don't have a `Global.asax.cs`.

Comment: The Global.asax file is where the application_startup event actually registers those API routes. The WebApiConfig.cs file must be called from the application start routine to properly register it.

Comment: Now I made a new project, but it was an example project or something? It already had lots of files (Not only the template files) with just customer information.... So how do I make a **clean** project?

Comment: Do I need to chose `New project` > `ASP.NET Web Application` > `Web API`?

Comment: Yes, that is the project. You ignore the extra files, the one you are interested in is the Global.asax file.

Comment: I know, I already tried to make the `Global.asax` file by my own but how do I create a new `.asax` file?

Comment: See my edit of my answer to add new .asax, excuse the formatting, it is hard to format on phone.

Comment: Yes now it is atleast doing something. I get this error now `"Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."`, if you quickly know how to fix this, that would be perfect. But else I think I'm able to figure that out myself.

Comment: Try and add [HttpGet] to the top of the Method.

Comment: You sir, You. Are. Awesome. Seriously thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Haha no worries. I am glad I could help Goldenowner good luck and have fun :)